# Java script game - adding more questions

Tags: javascript, function, events, pattern-matching

I am trying to make a matching game in java script, where you match the correct animal print to the animal. I have three questions in the game so far and when I try to add more, the game does not show any questions..

If anyone could help in anyway that would be great.

Here is the code..

```
    <html>   
    <head>
    <Script>

    function randSort (a,b) {return Math.random() - 0.5}

    var questions = [
    {text: " What animal is this?", img: "AnimalPrints/1.jpg", answers: ["Cheetah", "Tiger", "Ladybird"], ans: "0"},

    {text: " What animal is this one?", img: "AnimalPrints/2.jpg", answers: ["Elephant", "Giraffe", "Snake"], ans: "1"},

    {text: "What animal is this one please?", img: "AnimalPrints/3.jpg", answers: ["Bumblebee", "Tiger", "Lady bird"], ans: "2"}

    /////**part I added**///

    {text: "What animal is this one please?", img: "AnimalPrints/4.jpg", answers: ["Giraffe", "Butterfly", "Monkey"], ans: "2"}

    ];

    var correctCount = 0;
    var currentQ = 0;

    function select(nr) {
        if (nr == questions[currentQ].ans)
        {
            correctCount++;
            document.getElementById('display').innerHTML= "You win"
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('display').innerHTML= "You lose"
        }

        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML += "<p>Score: "+ correctCount; 
        // if its the last one

        nextQ(); 
    }    

    function showQ() {
        document.getElementById('questionText').innerHTML = questions[currentQ].text;  
        document.getElementById('animalPrint').src = questions[currentQ].img;

        newhtml = "";
        for (var i = 0; i< questions[currentQ].answers.length; i++)
        {
            newhtml+= "<button onclick = 'select(" + i + ")'>"+ questions[currentQ].answers[i] + "</button>";

        }

        document.getElementById('alloptions').innerHTML = newhtml;
    }


    function nextQ(){
        if (currentQ < questions.length-1)
        {    
            currentQ++;

            showQ();
        }

    }

    window.onload =init;

    function init()
    {
        correctCount = 0;
        questions.sort(randSort);
        currentQ = 0;
        showQ();
    }



    </script>
        <title> Game_page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href ="gamepage_css.css">
            <script type = "text/javascript">
    /*
                    document.write("<img src = \ "" + Math.floor 1 + Math.random() * 10) +
                    ".jpg\" />");



                    document.write("<img src = \"" + Math.floor 1 + Math.random() * )
    */                

            </script>        

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = main>
            <div id = "questionText"> Testing</div>
            <div id ="animal">
                <img id = "animalPrint" src = "AnimalPrints/1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div id = "alloptions">
            </div>


            <button id = "nextbutton" onclick = "nextQ();">
            </button></a>


        </div>

        <div id = "display">    Score:    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

and the CSS

```
body {
    background-position: center;
    background-color:lime;
}

#questionText {width: 350px; background: white;}


#nextbutton {
    background-image: url(Buttons/nextbutton.jpg);
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-position: center;
    width:100px;
    height:44px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    border-radius:10px;
}


#main {
    margin-top:200px;
    margin-left:250px;
    border:1px solid red;
    width:600px;
}

#display {
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
    border-radius:5px;
    font-family:aqua;
}
```

Comment: Can you show what part of the code that you changed?  How it looks before and after your update?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I edited it there to this part of the code I added, which cancels out the other questions for some reason..

Comment: Just making sure, but did you add another comma before your fourth question? and close your array?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to change answers and it works for me

```
var questions = [
{text: " What animal is this?", img: "AnimalPrints/1.jpg", answers: ["Cheetah", "Tiger", "Ladybird"], ans: "0"},

{text: " What animal is this one?", img: "AnimalPrints/2.jpg", answers: ["Elephant", "Giraffe", "Snake"], ans: "1"},

{text: "What animal is this one please?", img: "AnimalPrints/3.jpg", answers: ["Bumblebee", "Tiger", "Lady bird"], ans: "2"},
{text: "test question?", img: "AnimalPrints/3.jpg", answers: ["answer 1", "answer 2", "answer 3"], ans: "2"}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears as Four_lo suggests in his/her comment that you are missing a "," after your third choice in the array.  Doing so displays it.

http://jsbin.com/quvadekaru/1/edit